# How to test value in files and output read another variable which tally to test value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need advice as per the below situation

cat file1

ServerA|2

ServerB|1

so I need to know how can I test  value no 2 which is not  meet 2 = 2 then print  value no 1

**in the above we know that ServerB is not met.

Sample output

ServerB has a value 1

** But let's says all value met 2=2; then the output will

All are Good

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered to see how to format your input, output, and code as "Code Blocks" and then [edit] your question to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

**file1**

```
ServerA|2
ServerB|1
```

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

allfine=true

while IFS= read -r line
do
    read -r firstfield secondfield <<< "$(echo "$line" | awk -F'|' '{print $1 " " $2}')"
    if [[ $secondfield -eq 1 ]]
    then
        echo "$firstfield has a value 1"
        allfine=false
    fi
done < file1

if [[ "$allfine" == "true" ]]
then
    echo "All are Good"
fi
```

- read the file line per line
- extract the first and second value, using `|` as separator
- if the second value is == 1, print a message
- if all values == 2, print a message based on the value of variable `allfine`